# Как правильно использовать чужой код с MIT лицензией в своем проекте без MIT лицензии?

Tags: лицензирование

Я создал репозиторий на основе темплейта, который лицензирован MIT лицензией. Мой репозиторий значительно отличается в конечном счете от исходного темплейта, и я не хочу, чтобы мой репозиторий имел MIT лицензию и не хочу, чтобы в файле *package.json* был указан автор изначального темплейта. Но, насколько я понимаю, единственное условие использования кода под MIT лицензией - это сохранение файла LICENSE с указанием владельца MIT лицензии.

Как указать на то, что часть кода принадлежит владельцу темплейта, но не сохранять при этом лицензию MIT на моем репозитории и указать авторство репозитория в *package.json*?

Comment: Другими словами, вы хотите сплагиатить чужой код и выдавать его за свой? imho никаких реальных последствий не будет, вряд ли кто-то это вообще заметит

Comment: Темплейт мне нужен исключительно для быстрой инициализации проекта, подобно CRA. Это способ сэкономить время. На данном этапе разработки от темплейта остались только конфиги и структура проекта. Все наполнение логикой я создаю сам

Comment: Не уверен, считаются ли вообще конфиги и структуры объектами авторского права